# Add TFS 2010 users from different domain

Tags: team-foundation-server

How can I allow users from different domain to access the team foundation server ?
The situation is that the TFS is installed on domain X and I need to grant access to users from domain Y. domain X and Y are not in the same tree. So the situation is of providing access to users from domain xxx@X.com and xxx@Y.com. How can this be done ?

TIA

Comment: Trust relationship established?

Answer (score 1):

Your only choice is to establish trust relationships between the two domains in AD.